# How to shadow a record in F# Program.fs?

Tags: f#, shadowing

I'm following the F# book [Get Programming with F#](https://www.manning.com/books/get-programming-with-f-sharp) and got to the part about shadowing. The simplest example they provide doesn't seem to be possible, so I'm wondering if either this syntax was removed or changed for F# 6 shadowing? I haven't been able to find anything stating that or how to do what the book offers as shadowing a record.

```ml
type Address =
    { Street: string
      Town: string
      City: string }

let home = { Street = "123 Main Street"; Town = "The Town"; City = "The City" }
let home = { home with City = "Second City" }
let home = { home with City = "Third City" }
```

When trying to build get an error stating: `Duplicate definition of value 'home'`

---

Edit

So after searching for answers without success as to why this doesn't work I tried putting the above into a function like so:

```ml
let testFunction = 
    let home = { Street = "123 Main Street"; Town = "The Town"; City = "The City" }
    let home = { home with City = "Second City" }
    let home = { home with City = "Third City" }
    0
```

and it worked just fine. So my question now is why does shadowing work within a function but not outside? Is there a conflict with scoping on a module level that doesn't happen within a function's scope?

Comment: Top-level definitions in a module kind of don't make sense that way. I mean, why would you want to do this, what's the goal? It does work in a script though.

Comment: Just to add, the reason why it works in a script is that it's a subtle difference in checking done for scripts. As you might imagine, iterating in a script/reply with a bunch of top-level values whose definitions change as you experiment is an important scenario. But the same isn't really true for top-level values in an actual program.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin reason is that I'm learning F# so I wanted to run an example from the book, which until this point has been in Program.fs vs separated out more properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add some more detail to the existing answers, there are four different cases.

**Local definitions.** If you are inside a function body, you can use shadowing and this is quite useful when doing a computation in multiple steps:

```
let adjust index = 
  let index = max 0 index
  let index = min 100 index
  index
```

**Local definitions inside class.** You are similarly allowed to shadow local definitions inside a class:

```
type A() = 
  let foo = 1
  let foo = 2
  member x.Foo = foo
```

**Top-level in a script file.** If you are at the top level in a script file (`something.fsx`) then you are allowed shadowing. The idea with script files is that they would be run manually, so it is useful to have multiple different versions - you just run the one you want by hand:

```
let test = calculation1 ()
let test = caluclation2 ()
```

**Top-level in a module (source file).** The only case where shadowing does *not* work is when you are in a module (or `.fs` file which becomes a module implicitly). In a module, definitions are public and they are compiled as static members of a class, so there is also a technical limitation (you cannot have multiple class members of the same name).

```
module Constants = 
  let answer = 1
  let answer = 42 // error FS0037: Duplicate definition of value
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why shadowing is limited to function body?

*There are probably some technical reasons. But the core reasons are IMO:*

**Naming** is hard. Shadowing eases the pain but it can be confusing.

Also F# supports "tick naming" (`home'`) to have a similar but different name. It's a kind of safer shadowing.

Comment: The technical reasons are why I cam here because I couldn't find them. This is helpful info too though. Thanks for the suggestions and insight.